# Killing a process shuts uvicorn server down inside Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, python-multiprocessing, uvicorn

I prepared a worker for data processing. When a request comes to this route

```
 @worker.post('/process/production-process-monthly/start', tags=["worker"])
 async def calculate_solar_monthly(
   config: Settings = Depends(get_setting),
    body: Union[CalculateSolarEnergyMonthly, None] = Body(
        None, title="These values are for choosing the calculation model of the accumulated data.",
        description="Refers to units not like electricity, natural gas, oil.",
        alias="body"),
    # token: dict = Depends(token_decoder)):
  try:
    log.info(f"-> Calculating operation time")
    log.warning("-" * 60)
    start = time.time()

    business = 'hktm'  # we will get this from token.
    # return an error if there is a process with the same ID as a process in the processes list
    process_id = f"{config.keyspace_name}.{business}_monthly_test"
    existing_process = next(
        (p for p in processes if p["id"] == process_id), None)
    if existing_process:
        return JSONResponse(content={"message": f"{process_id} is not RUNNING. Duplicated error."},
                            status_code=500)
    # run main function in parallel using multiprocessing.Process
    p = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=monthlyProcess, args=(config, body, business))
    p.start()
    # run main function in parallel using multiprocessing.Process
    processes.append({"p": p, "id": process_id})
except:
    return JSONResponse(
        content=config.err.WORKER_PROCESS_START_ERROR,
        status_code=500,
    )
```

It opens a main process. Inside which opening a subprocess for every table and doing some parallel operations. Im opening the subprocesses like this:

```
    for table in table_names:
        if table.endswith('daily_testx'):
            tables.append(table)

    # List to store subprocesses
    # newTable = []
    # newTable.append(tables[0])

    while True:
        start_time = time.time()
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=len(tables)) as pool:
            pool.starmap(startMonthlyProcess, [
                        (table, config, body, business) for table in tables])
            pool.close()
            pool.join()

        log.warning(
            "Process finished --- %s seconds ---" %
            (time.time() - start_time))

        time.sleep(body.period * 60)
```

in here I put the subprocess logic inside a loop to keep the operation alive. Every given time it's opening subprocesses and when they are finished it logs the total calculation time. If I want to stop the worker then I send a request to this endpoint:

```
@worker.delete('/process/production-process-monthly/stop', tags=["worker"])
async def calculate_solar_daily(
config: Settings = Depends(get_setting),
process_name: Union[str, None] = Query(
    None, title="Update key", description="Update object values.", 
alias="process_name"),
key_prefix: Union[str, None] = Query(
    None, title="Update key", description="Update object values.", alias="key_prefix")):
if process_name == None:
    return JSONResponse(content={"message": f"{process_name} is not Stopped. The variable contains a NULL value."},
                        status_code=500)
try:
    delete_redis_keys_of_pa(config, key_prefix)
    for idx, p in enumerate(processes):
        if p["id"].endswith(process_name):
            # print(p["p"])
            p = p["p"]
            log.info(p)
            # print('p in,', p)
            # parentpid = p._parent_pid
            try:
               os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
            except Exception as ex:
                log.info(f"### {ex} happened")
            # p.terminate()
            processes.pop(idx)
            log.info(
                colored("message: Stopped process with ID ", "blue") + colored(f" 
{p.pid}", "yellow") + colored(" Stopped", "red"))
```

The problem starts in here. In my local when I kill the main process the subprocesses are also being killed if any left unfinished. But when I compose up this service in docker, the start mechanism works as how I wanted but the stop mechanism is going wild. It kills the main process and deletes the redis keys, I can also see the process Id but after kill command the uvicorn is shutting itself down. Its shown in below;

```
2023-09-25 13:26:20 0bcd0b1e3552 Worker ROUTE[1] INFO <Process name='Process-1' 
pid=27 parent=1 started>
2023-09-25 13:26:20 0bcd0b1e3552 Worker ROUTE[1] INFO message: Stopped process with ID 27 Stopped
2023-09-25 13:26:20 0bcd0b1e3552 uvicorn.error[1] INFO Shutting down
INFO:     192.168.128.11:42780 - "DELETE /api/v1/cost/process/production-process-monthly/stop?process_name=monthly_test&key_prefix=daily_testx HTTP/1.0" 200 OK
2023-09-25 13:26:21 0bcd0b1e3552 uvicorn.error[1] INFO Waiting for application shutdown.
2023-09-25 13:26:21 0bcd0b1e3552 uvicorn.error[1] INFO Application shutdown complete.
2023-09-25 13:26:21 0bcd0b1e3552 uvicorn.error[1] INFO Finished server process [1]
```

Later I realized that the subprocesses are continuing their work because I saw their logs. But I cant send any request to the service, it being locked. How can I kill the process I created in route without causing uvicorn server to shutdown?

Edit: I confirmed that inside the container the process is not being killed. Although uvicorn is shutting down, the process is being executed in the background.

Edit 2: After hours of trial and error I found a way to solve this problem. At first I thought main process was being killed but subprocesses wasnt. Then I realized the main process also not being killed. But uvicorn was shutting down. So the process was like being sent to limbo. I couldnt reach uvicorn couldnt reach.

Later I came across the [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) . I integrated this to my entrypoint. Then I changed the delete function. I used SIGKILL instead of SIGTERM or p.terminate(). Now it successfully deletes the process. But Im not sure how much is this a healthy way to solve this. Any ideas still much appreciated.